# Session retaining stale values when using Angular $http.post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, ruby-on-rails-5

From what I have been seeing in my app, if I my controller using an AngularJs $http.get request, I can't update session data in the controller that handles this request because a render :json=> data type response doesn't update the session cookie on the client. I'm not sure that is actually true, but that what seems to be happening.

If it is true though it seems like if I use devise, for example, and initialize a a session variable, e.g. session[:foo]="bar" in session#create, and then subsequently I have an angular module which executes a $http.get, which is handled by, say, account#my_method, as follows

```
def my_method
      session[:foo]="baz"
      [do something]
      render :json => {status: "OK"}
end
```

the session[:foo] change will not be persisted in the user's session cookie thus the next time the user hits a controller session[:foo] will still equal "bar", not "baz".

It seems unlikely, but that looks like what I'm seeing as I debug my application.    If so would using a database or memcache session store work better, since the change would happen server side and would not require updating the client side cookie?   Or is there a way to handle session updates when using Ajax type methods like $http.get in AngularJs

Comment: Is the XHR cross-domain? `XMLHttpRequest` responses from a different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless `withCredentials` is set to `true` before making the request.

Comment: Nope, all of these urls hit my server.